# Detect if two users are using same page php

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have pages on which users write and store their data. This is share-able with other users too and they can edit it as well. I want to detect if two users are editing it at the same time. As if two users are editing and saving it at same time then they would overwrite each other.

So I want to detect this that how many users are on this page and if two or more users are editing at same time or not. With this I will halt other users from editing and when no user is editing it then the other one can edit.

So please tell me the techniques how can I detect that. I store pages id in the session. Please tell all the possible ways and their pros and cons.

Comment: One would overwrite the other, they wouldn't overwrite _each other_. Other than that, what have you got so far? Why didn't it work?

Comment: This question demonstrates no attempt to research or solve the problem. Please read the help section on asking questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: Do you mean you want to track users in real time?

Comment: @Yashan Mittal If yes then you need to use some server javascript combination. You can use either Node.js with socket io or you can you ejabber server with strophe javascript library. As far for how you have to add more details to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could save the datetime when the page was opened for editing and the datetime when the page was saved.  When it's saved, check if the datetime when it was opened is greater than the datetime when it was last saved before saving.  If it is more recent, then it's not overwritten; otherwise, it likely is being overwritten.

Comment: A similar approach could have the client keep a hash of the page contents when he began editing, and check this against the hash of the page when it is being saved. If they don't match, the page has changed.

Answer (score 0):

An idea could be to save in a database table related to the user the id of the page and a timestamp.
When an user commits an edit to the photo, you can check if the timestamp previewsly saved is less than the timestamp of the page edit, then inform the user.

Another solution is to send periodically an ajax request to the server to be getting informed of other users actions in that page.